# Magento not sending forgot password emails

Tags: magento, magento-1.5

When a customer tries to reset their password Magento is not sending the emails. I do know that Magento is resetting the password but the mails are just not sending out

Here is the code that sends the mails I think. Please help.

```
public function sendPasswordReminderEmail()
{
    $translate = Mage::getSingleton('core/translate');
    /* @var $translate Mage_Core_Model_Translate */
    $translate->setTranslateInline(false);

    $storeId = $this->getStoreId();
    if (!$storeId) {
        $storeId = $this->_getWebsiteStoreId();
    }

    Mage::getModel('core/email_template')
        ->setDesignConfig(array('area'=>'frontend', 'store'=>$storeId))
        ->sendTransactional(
            Mage::getStoreConfig(self::XML_PATH_FORGOT_EMAIL_TEMPLATE, $storeId),
            Mage::getStoreConfig(self::XML_PATH_FORGOT_EMAIL_IDENTITY, $storeId),
            $this->getEmail(),
            $this->getName(),
            array('customer'=>$this)
        );

    $translate->setTranslateInline(true);

    return $this;
}
```

Comment: Please check that Magento is at least sending emails. Also have you played with template customizations (transactional emails) recently?

Answer (score 2):

I just answered a similar answer over here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10810193/778669

In short; go to `Admin > System > Configuration > Advanced > System > Mail Sending Settings` and make sure `Disable Email Communications` is set to `No`, this was the problem for me.