# magento not sending out any mails, how to debug?

Tags: php, debugging, magento, zend-framework, zend-mail

`Magento` is not sending out any emails, transnational, contact form gives error

```
 cannot send your mail at this moment
```

I checked

- Mail setup in magento, all email accounts are set in settings
- php mail works fine a test.php with php mail sends out a message
- checked my mailserver logs but see nothing there no errors
- /var/log/system.log and exception.log shows only an error not the cause of the error

  `exception 'Zend_Mail_Transport_Exception' with 
   message 'Unable to send mail. ' in 
  /var/webshop/httpdocs/lib/Zend/Mail/Transport/Sendmail.php:137`

Answer (score 26):

I ran into this problem when Magento was not sending out forgot password emails (yet reporting it did to the user) then after looking in `/var/log/exception.log` found the error it was generating was:

```
2012-05-30T04:27:54+00:00 ERR (3): 
exception 'Exception' with message 'This letter cannot be sent.' in /home/magento/www/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Email/Template.php:354
Stack trace:
#0 /home/magento/www/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Email/Template.php(463): Mage_Core_Model_Email_Template->send(Array, Array, Array)
#1 /home/magento/www/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Email/Template/Mailer.php(79): Mage_Core_Model_Email_Template->sendTransactional('customer_passwo...', 'support', Array, Array, Array, '1')
#2 /home/magento/www/app/code/core/Mage/Customer/Model/Customer.php(646): Mage_Core_Model_Email_Template_Mailer->send()
#3 /home/magento/www/app/code/core/Mage/Customer/Model/Customer.php(663): Mage_Customer_Model_Customer->_sendEmailTemplate('customer/passwo...', 'customer/passwo...', Array, '1')
#4 /home/magento/www/app/code/core/Mage/Customer/controllers/AccountController.php(554): Mage_Customer_Model_Customer->sendPasswordResetConfirmationEmail()
#5 /home/magento/www/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(420): Mage_Customer_AccountController->forgotPasswordPostAction()
#6 /home/magento/www/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Standard.php(250): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch('forgotpasswordp...')
#7 /home/magento/www/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php(176): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
#8 /home/magento/www/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(349): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()
#9 /home/magento/www/app/Mage.php(640): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#10 /home/magento/www/index.php(84): Mage::run('default', 'store')
#11 {main}
```

So opened up `/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Email/Template.php` and found the code that was throwing this error (on line 354) was:

```
if (!$this->isValidForSend()) {
    Mage::logException(new Exception('This letter cannot be sent.')); // translation is intentionally omitted
    return false;
}
```

So had a look at `isValidForSend()`:

```
public function isValidForSend()
{
    return !Mage::getStoreConfigFlag('system/smtp/disable')
        && $this->getSenderName()
        && $this->getSenderEmail()
        && $this->getTemplateSubject();
}
```

Added some logging of the variables at the start of the function as one of these must be returning `false`:

```
Mage::Log(var_export(!Mage::getStoreConfigFlag('system/smtp/disable'),true).';'.var_export($this->getSenderName(),true).';'.var_export($this->getSenderEmail(),true).';'.var_export($this->getTemplateSubject(),true),null,'email.log');
```

Which creates the log file `/var/log/email.log` which had:

```
2012-05-30T04:44:37+00:00 DEBUG (7): false;'CustomerSupport';'support@example.com';'Password Reset Confirmation for {{var customer.name}}'
```

So the problem was: `!Mage::getStoreConfigFlag('system/smtp/disable')` which you can fix up in `Admin > System > Configuration > Advanced > System > Mail Sending Settings` and change `Disable Email Communications` to `No` so the emails are **NOT** disabled.

Now it works :)

Answer (score 2):

Any php program can do a half-decent job of sending out some email with phpmail.

Given the error message, What your Magento build is trying to do is different - use Sendmail via the Zend library.

You will need to build and test your sendmail installation. Or use some other mail service such as gmail and get Magento to use that.

To test whether it is you, your computer or Magento, put some other program such as Roundcube Mail on there. If Roundcube Mail can send mail then you will know Sendmail is working, if not then you will know the problem is in Sendmail.

Fixing your Sendmail is distro specific.

Comment: I added an smtp module for magento that supports authentication but it still is trying to send mail true the sendmail transport/sendmail.php :S very frustrating, regular php scripts work fine with mail magento will just not send any email transactional or contact form.

Comment: Roundcube sends mail out fine, how could I make magento make sending mails also? Any suggestion on thix? Thx!

Answer (score 2):

I also struggled with the problem of order e-mails not being sent in CE 1.9.1 but found the problem after a while:

As of Magento CE 1.9.1 Magento doesn't send order emails directly during the order process.
Instead the mails are queued and are sent by the cron.
So make sure to configure the Magento cronjob properly.

Also refer to:

http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/ee1141-ce191-responsive-email#cron
http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/ce18-and-ee113-installing#install-cron

Answer (score 1):

That can be `sendmail` problem, if `Magento` sending emails with `php` default transport.

I'm experienced with situation when sendmail deny emails for local domain, instead of relay those emails to MX servers

http://www.masterdef.net/blog/magento-unable-to-send-mail-sendmail-configuration/#more-1

I recommend check `mail.log` on server, and found if there is errors like a `user unknown`
that mean wrong `sendmail` configuration

Answer (score 1):

```
public function isValidForSend()
{
    return !Mage::getStoreConfigFlag('system/smtp/disable')
        && $this->getSenderName()
        && $this->getSenderEmail()
        && $this->getTemplateSubject();
}
```

also, in my case error log took me to this function. Configuration in admin was fine. But $this->getTemplateSubject() was sending false value as template was missing under /app/locale/ folder. So added template that was missing. After that it worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

If there is a problem with the email template .You get this error.So before checking the email logs check your email template , moreover when its a custom email template , the code is not broken .