# Magento: Email stuck in queue? 'This letter cannot be sent.'

Tags: php, email, magento

Something strange is going on with my Magento install. Everything with the emails used to work fine, but now I have these messages in my exception.log:

```
2015-05-11T10:00:02+00:00 ERR (3):
exception 'Exception' with message 'This letter cannot be sent.' in /var/www/vhosts/lvps91-250-119-53.dedicated.hosteurope.de/httpdocs/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Email/Template.php:399
Stack trace:
#0 /var/www/vhosts/lvps91-250-119-53.dedicated.hosteurope.de/httpdocs/magento/app/code/community/Ebizmarts/Mandrill/Model/Email/Template.php(24): Mage_Core_Model_Email_Template->send('info@mysite.de', 'mysite', Array)
#1 /var/www/vhosts/lvps91-250-119-53.dedicated.hosteurope.de/httpdocs/magento/app/code/community/Hackathon/MageMonitoring/Model/WatchDog/UberDog.php(108): Ebizmarts_Mandrill_Model_Email_Template->send('info@mysite.de', 'mysite', Array)
#2 [internal function]: Hackathon_MageMonitoring_Model_WatchDog_UberDog->triggerActiveDogs(Object(Mage_Cron_Model_Schedule))
#3 /var/www/vhosts/lvps91-250-119-53.dedicated.hosteurope.de/httpdocs/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Cron/Model/Observer.php(325): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
#4 /var/www/vhosts/lvps91-250-119-53.dedicated.hosteurope.de/httpdocs/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Cron/Model/Observer.php(72): Mage_Cron_Model_Observer->_processJob(Object(Mage_Cron_Model_Schedule), Object(Mage_Core_Model_Config_Element))
#5 /var/www/vhosts/lvps91-250-119-53.dedicated.hosteurope.de/httpdocs/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(1338): Mage_Cron_Model_Observer->dispatch(Object(Varien_Event_Observer))
#6 /var/www/vhosts/lvps91-250-119-53.dedicated.hosteurope.de/httpdocs/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(1317): Mage_Core_Model_App->_callObserverMethod(Object(Mage_Cron_Model_Observer), 'dispatch', Object(Varien_Event_Observer))
#7 /var/www/vhosts/lvps91-250-119-53.dedicated.hosteurope.de/httpdocs/magento/app/Mage.php(448): Mage_Core_Model_App->dispatchEvent('default', Array)
#8 /var/www/vhosts/lvps91-250-119-53.dedicated.hosteurope.de/httpdocs/magento/cron.php(76): Mage::dispatchEvent('default')
#9 {main}
```

This is written to the log files every 5 minutes so I guess it must be the cronjob trying to send out mail and failing.

I tried tracking the problem and it was caused by this function in Template.php to return false:

```
$this->isValidForSend()
```

So following [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9393220/magento-not-sending-out-any-mails-how-to-debug) advice I added this line to the function to figure out why it would return false. It just writes the results of isValidForSend to an email.log file.

```
Mage::Log(var_export(!Mage::getStoreConfigFlag('system/smtp/disable'),true).';'.var_export($this->getSenderName(),true).';'.var_export($this->getSenderEmail(),true).';'.var_export($this->getTemplateSubject(),true),null,'email.log');
```

The results from email.log:

```
2015-05-11T08:35:02+00:00 DEBUG (7): true;'MACHIMA';'info@mysite.de';NULL
2015-05-11T08:40:02+00:00 DEBUG (7): true;'MACHIMA';'info@mysite.de';NULL
2015-05-11T08:45:02+00:00 DEBUG (7): true;'MACHIMA';'info@mysite.de';NULL
2015-05-11T08:50:02+00:00 DEBUG (7): true;'MACHIMA';'info@mysite.de';NULL
```

So everything seems to be ok, just the last NULL value which is returned by

```
$this->getTemplateSubject()
```

causes the function to fail.

I checked the configuration about 10 times and don't find any emails that are being sent out and are missing a subject.

My thought now is that maybe there is an email stuck in a queue Magento keeps trying to send out every 5 minutes.

Is there a way to track down where this is coming from?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I think you have some community modules installed but not well-configured. If you look at the thrown exception you see a module called `Ebizmarts` which extends Magento Email template. I have seen also this module specializes in Email marketing (which could be our problematic Emails!); so first of all make sure it is configured correctly. You can find its manuals [here](http://wiki.ebizmarts.com/sage-pay-installation).

Alternatively a good way to track exceptions could be temporarily disabling external modules to see if they persist or not.

Comment: I already disabled Ebizsmart and never used it. I just used it in combination with Mailchimp where it calls the API. But I am pretty sure that this is the culprit. I just need it for Mailchimp and don't know what else to do besides disabling it

Comment: @ØleBjarnstroem you don't have to disable it. Just figure out how to configure it - [Here](http://ebizmarts.com/forums/topics/view/8800/10), this person was suffering from the same issue (if you have missed it).